# Can't get this Tic Tac Toe Game to play fair

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, tic-tac-toe

This is a tic tac toe game to cooperate with me.  I have originally created this game in the beginning of the semester, however out instructor wants us to now add an AI ( artificial intelligence ), which can imitate another player. The best approach I took is to make a method that has a random number generator.  This worked for me, however when I was running the tic tac toe game the 2nd player AI would overwrite the 1st player move.  So in order to prevent this from happening I put in a conditional statement which can check if the Jbuttun is disabled.  However it is not allowing me to compile.  Then error it is giving is incompatible type: ( required Boolean: found Void).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{
private final int HEIGHT = 450;
private final int WIDTH = 500;
private static JButton [] button = new JButton[9];
private static Action [] playerTurn = new Action[9];
private Font arial = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
private static int lockButtons = 0;
private boolean game = false;
private static Random  rNum = new  Random(); 



public TicTacToe ()
{
    setTitle( "TTT");
    setSize( HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {

        button[i] = new JButton( "B" + (i + 1));
        playerTurn[i] = new Action();
        add(button[i]);
        button[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,10));
        button[i].setFont(arial);
        button[i].addActionListener(playerTurn[i]);
    }


    setVisible(true);
}

private class Action implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent playerMove)
    {
        //Get button pressed using GetSource Command
        JButton whatPlayer=(JButton)(playerMove.getSource()); 

                for ( int x =0; x <= button.length; x++)
                {
                    whatPlayer.setText("o");
                    whatPlayer.setEnabled(false);
                    validate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Computer's Turn ");
                    player2();
                    break;
                }
    }

    public void player2()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i <= button.length ; i++)
        {   
                    int num = rNum.nextInt(8);
                    button[num].setText( "x");
                    button[num].setEnabled(false);
                    validate();

                // This is the block that is causing the compiler error 
                /*if( button[i].setEnabled(false))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
                    break;
                }*/
                    break;
        }       
    }

    public void validate()
    {
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[1].getText()) && button[1].getText().equals(button[2].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[3].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[5].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[3].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[6].getText().equals(button[7].getText()) && button[7].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[6].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[3].getText()) && button[3].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[5].getText()) && button[5].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<button.length;i++)
        {
            if(button[i].isEnabled())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == button.length)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This was a Draw");
        }
    }
    public void gameOver()
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < button.length; x++)
        {
            button[x].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}   
}
```

Comment: Your question says your code has a compile error. But it compiles just fine.

Comment: I know I have a condition statement in my player 2 method that has been placed as a block statement, since it is in a block statement it will compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( button[i].setEnabled(false))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
    break;
}
```

You are indeed trying to check a void type in a conditional statement, this can't be done.
Since setEnabled returns void (nothing).
What you should be doing is checking the getter method of 'Enabled', so:

```
if (!button[i].isEnabled()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
    break;
}
```

Note the '!' before the statement, this makes it negative

Comment: Ok I just tried your solution it did the job, however this condition is being executed all the time, not just if the button is enabled or disabled.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain this, the code within the statement can't run unless the button is in fact disabled. I can only suggest you look at the code right above it, since it's unclear to me what your purpose is there. Also in the code within the 'actionPerformed' method, you are setting every button to disabled. And I never see you enabling any button anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( button[i].setEnabled(false))
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
   break;
}
```

`setEnabled()` returns void that's why it gives you error, maybe you mean `.isEnabled()`?

```
if(!button[i].isEnabled())
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Button is disables ");
   break;
}
```

`isEnabled()` returns true if the button is enabled, false if disabled.

Comment: Ok I just tried your solution it did the job, however this condition is being executed all the time, not just if the button is enabled or disabled

Comment: I think you should a bit change the logic of the player2 method, and i think you should do if (button[num].isEnabled()) continue; after int num = rNum.nextInt(8);